# Get a list that is written as a string

Tags: python, string, list, extract

I currently have a list of strings, the strings are a list but in a string (see below). I would like to make this a list of lists.

I currently have:

```
mylist = ['[1, 2]', '[2, 4, 9]', '[3]']
```

and I would like to end up with

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [2, 4, 9] [3]]
```

I have thought about using list() to make the elements a list, similar to the way int() makes a string into an integer. Also, split() isn't that useful to me as it just breaks everything down into one character strings and recreating the list from these could be messy.

Any quick way to do this which I might be missing?

Comment: What's `a`, `b`, `var`, `this` and `that`?

Comment: Edited so that they are all numbers - in theory they could be anything, here just numbers would do. It's more of a question to ask if there is an easy way to get them out of the string.

Comment: Didn't see that article - thanks for the heads up. However, I got a malformed string error using that solution. Thankfully, the answer below solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use eval on your list:

```
myList = [eval(str) for str in myList]
```

Do watch out if your list contains user input though, since this could be used to execute unchecked code!

As user3286261 pointed out, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to avoid misuse of the standard eval.

Comment: User input is not the only way to exploit eval.

Answer (score 1):

ast.literal_eval is safer than eval:

```
import ast
mylist = [ast.literal_eval(str) for str in mylist]
```